# rolling joins in data.table with multiple matches

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

I have a remark/question about rolling joins
Let X,Y be:

```
set.seed(123);
X <- data.table(x=c(1,1,1,2,2),y=c(T,T,F,F,F),t=as.POSIXct("08:00:00.000",format="%H:%M:%OS")+sample(0:999,5,TRUE)/1e3)
Y <- copy(X)
set.seed(123)
Y[,`:=`(IDX=.I,t=t+sample(c(-5:5)/1e3,5,T))]
Y <- rbindlist(list(Y, X[5,][,IDX:=6][,t:=t+0.001], X[5,][,IDX:=7][,t:=t+0.002]))
setkey(X,x,y,t)
setkey(Y,x,y,t)
```

here `X` and `Y` are sorted by `x,y,t`

```
R) X
   x     y                       t
1: 1 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.407
2: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.286
3: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.788
4: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.882
5: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.940
R) Y
   x     y                       t IDX
1: 1 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.407   3
2: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.284   1
3: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.791   2
4: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.886   4
5: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.940   6
6: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.942   7
7: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.945   5
```

From

executing `Y[X, roll=-0.005]` gets you

```
R) Y[X, roll=-0.005]
       x     y                       t IDX
    1: 1 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.407  NA => due to precision the roll is no match
    2: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.286  NA => ok 
    3: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.788   2 => ok (x,y) matched and 788-791=-3
    4: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.882   4 => same
    5: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00.940   6 => NOT AN EXACT MATCH (precision)
```

So I would have expected to get more lines FOR THE LAST LINE as the default behaviour of "mult" is "all" and the last line of `X` is matched by lines `5,6, may be 7` of `Y`

Comment: I am interested in this because if we can get those additional lines we should be able to deal with window joins and compute rolling median,average or whatever

Comment: this sounds like a feature request to me (I'd use a vastly simpler example though, like `d = data.table(a = c(1.0,2.0,2.0), by = c(1:3), key = 'a'); d[J(2.1), ...]`, because this one is very hard to understand)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Row**

For the first row of `X` only the first row of `Y` has matching `x` and `y` so the first row of `Y` will match iff `Y$t[1]` is between `X$t[1]` and `X$t[1] + 0.005` but in fact `Y$t[1] < X$t[1]` as seen here:

```
> X$t[1] - Y$t[1]
Time difference of 0.0009999275 secs
```

One would need a positive `roll=` value whose magnitude is at least equal to the above difference in order to get a non-NA in row 1. e.g.

```
> Y[X, roll=0.001]
   x     y                   t IDX
1: 1 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   3
2: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
3: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
4: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
5: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
```

Note that you could force it by using `rollends=` like this:

```
> Y[X, roll = -0.005, rollends = TRUE]
   x     y                   t IDX
1: 1 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   3
2: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
3: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   2
4: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   4
5: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   6
```

**Last Row**

For the last row of `X` only row 5 of `Y` matches, not 5, 6 and 7, since only the nearest eligible row is a match.  `mult=` only applies to multiple matches and usually does not apply with `roll=` (see example at the bottom for an exception):

Note also that rows 5, 6 and 7 of `Y` do not have the same times.  They have increasing times so there is no possibility that they all match:

```
> dput(Y[["t"]])
structure(c(1371729600.407, 1371729600.285, 1371729600.791, 1371729600.887, 
1371729600.941, 1371729600.942, 1371729600.945), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))
```

Even if rows 5, 6 and 7 of `Y` have identical times if those times are not the same as the time in the last row of `X` then one only gets one row out.

```
> # times in rows 5, 6 and 7 of Y2 are same
> Y2 <- copy(Y)
> Y2[, t:= t[c(1:4, 5, 5, 5)]]
> setkey(Y2, x, y, t)
> Y2[X, roll = -0.005]
   x     y                   t IDX
1: 1 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
2: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
3: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   2
4: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   4
5: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   6
```

Its only if rows 5, 6 and 7 of 'Y' have the same times **and** the last row of `X` also has that time that one gets multiple times out and in that case `mult=` can apply:

```
> # time in row 5 of X2 same as the times in rows 5, 6 and 7 of Y2
> X2 <- copy(X)
> X2[, t:=c(t[1:4], Y2[["t"]][5])]
> Y2[X2, roll = -0.005]
   x     y                   t IDX
1: 1 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
2: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
3: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   2
4: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   4
5: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   6
6: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   7
7: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   5
> 
> Y2[X, roll = -0.005, mult = "first"]
   x     y                   t IDX
1: 1 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
2: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00  NA
3: 1  TRUE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   2
4: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   4
5: 2 FALSE 2013-06-20 08:00:00   6
```

How it works is not so clear from the documentation and I had to use trial and error to discover how it functions.  `?data.table` does say that *"Usually, there should be no duplicates in x's key"* (in our example here x is `Y`) so it may be that the developers wished to leave it undefined for this situation and open to future change.

The idea of using `mult=` as you describe does seem like a very interesting idea but it seems not to be the way it currently works.  Maybe it could in the future.

Comment: Have moved my comments to the answer.

Comment: I think OP is thinking that since in `d = data.table(a = c(1,2,2), b = c(1:3), key = 'a')` `d[J(2)]` matches both 2's, so should `d[J(2.1), roll = 1]` match both 2's when `mult` is set to `"all"`

Comment: I have added some additional exploratory code to see what happens in various situations.  See the last ADDED.