# Rolling join with multiple matches

Tags: r, join, data.table, rolling-computation

I have two data.tables, `dt1` and `dt2`. I want to join the two tables by a unique ID and by date. The dates might or might not match; hence, I have to use the `roll` feature. However, `dt2` can have multiple rows with the same ID and date and I want to match all of those rows.

A minimal example of the data structure:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(ID = 1:2,
                  Date = c(dmy("31122021"), dmy("31122022")),
                  Value1 = c("A", "B"))

dt2 <- data.table(ID = c(rep(1, times=6), rep(2, 8)),
                  Company = c(1:3, 1:3, 1:4, 1:4),
                  Date = c(rep(dmy("31122021"), times=3),
                           rep(dmy("31032022"), times=3),
                           rep(dmy("31032023"), times=4),
                           rep(dmy("30062023"), times=4)),
                  Value2 = 1:14)

setkey(dt1, ID, Date)
setkey(dt2, ID, Date)

dt1
   ID       Date Value1      Date1
1:  1 2021-12-31      A 2021-12-31
2:  2 2022-12-31      B 2022-12-31

dt2
    ID Company       Date Value2
 1:  1       1 2021-12-31      1
 2:  1       2 2021-12-31      2
 3:  1       3 2021-12-31      3
 4:  1       1 2022-03-31      4
 5:  1       2 2022-03-31      5
 6:  1       3 2022-03-31      6
 7:  2       1 2023-03-31      7
 8:  2       2 2023-03-31      8
 9:  2       3 2023-03-31      9
10:  2       4 2023-03-31     10
11:  2       1 2023-06-30     11
12:  2       2 2023-06-30     12
13:  2       3 2023-06-30     13
14:  2       4 2023-06-30     14
```

If I do the following, I only get a data.table with the row that includes Value2=7:

```
dt2[dt1, roll = "nearest"]
   ID Company       Date Value2 Value1      Date1
1:  1       1 2021-12-31      1      A 2021-12-31
2:  1       2 2021-12-31      2      A 2021-12-31
3:  1       3 2021-12-31      3      A 2021-12-31
4:  2       1 2022-12-31      7      B 2022-12-31
```

However, Value2=7 to 10 have all the same ID and date, so I would like all to be returned.

The following code gets me the desired result, but it is rather cumbersome and feels like a hack:

```
dt1[,Date1:=Date]
dt <- dt1[dt2, roll="nearest"]
dt[,DiffDate:=abs(as.numeric(Date1-Date))]
dt[,MinDiffDate:=min(DiffDate),by=ID]
dt <- dt[DiffDate==MinDiffDate]
dt

   ID       Date Value1      Date1 Company Value2 DiffDate MinDiffDate
1:  1 2021-12-31      A 2021-12-31       1      1        0           0
2:  1 2021-12-31      A 2021-12-31       2      2        0           0
3:  1 2021-12-31      A 2021-12-31       3      3        0           0
4:  2 2023-03-31      B 2022-12-31       1      7       90          90
5:  2 2023-03-31      B 2022-12-31       2      8       90          90
6:  2 2023-03-31      B 2022-12-31       3      9       90          90
7:  2 2023-03-31      B 2022-12-31       4     10       90          90
```

Other questions on SO had similar issues, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216843/rolling-joins-in-data-table-with-multiple-matches) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540746/rolling-joins-on-multiple-matches). But the first link implies there is no solution and the solution proposed in the second link does not generate the desired result:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540746/rolling-joins-on-multiple-matches
DT1 <- dt2[dt1, roll="nearest"]
DT2 <- dt1[dt2, roll = "nearest"]
dt_match <- unique(rbindlist(list(DT1, DT2), use.names=TRUE))
dt_match

    ID Company       Date Value2 Value1
 1:  1       1 2021-12-31      1      A
 2:  1       2 2021-12-31      2      A
 3:  1       3 2021-12-31      3      A
 4:  2       1 2022-12-31      7      B
 5:  1       1 2022-03-31      4      A
 6:  1       2 2022-03-31      5      A
 7:  1       3 2022-03-31      6      A
 8:  2       1 2023-03-31      7      B
 9:  2       2 2023-03-31      8      B
10:  2       3 2023-03-31      9      B
11:  2       4 2023-03-31     10      B
12:  2       1 2023-06-30     11      B
13:  2       2 2023-06-30     12      B
14:  2       3 2023-06-30     13      B
15:  2       4 2023-06-30     14      B
```

Is there a better solution than the one proposed by me to perform a rolling merge with several matches?

**Update as response to r2evans' answer**

`dt1` includes many more columns that I want to keep - I adjust it now to include two more:

```
dt1 <- data.table(ID = 1:2,
                  Date = c(dmy("31122021"), dmy("31122022")),
                  Value1 = c("A", "B"),
                  Info1  = c("Info x", "Info y"),
                  Info2  = c("Info 1", "Info 2"))
```

How can I adjust the call `dt2[, Date1:=Date][dt1, .(ID, Date=Date1, Value1), roll=-Inf]` in such a way that I don't have to manually type the columns? I tried something like this but this doesn't work - I guess I can only use this to get columns, not also rename them:

```
colnames <- c("Date=Date1", names(dt1)[names(dt1)!="Date"])
dt2[
  unique(dt2[, Date1 := Date][dt1, colnames, with=FALSE, roll = -Inf]),
  on=.(ID, Date)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can keep it to a single join and avoid filtering on a larger-than-necessary join by "collapsing" `Company` and `Value2`, performing the rolling join, then "expanding" `Company` and `Value2` back out.

```
dt2[
  # "collapse" Company and Value2
  ,.(Company = .(Company), Value2 = .(Value2), Date2 = Date), .(ID, Date)
][
  dt1, on = .(ID, Date), roll = "nearest" # perform the rolling join
][
  # "expand" the collapsed columns back out
  ,lapply(.SD, \(x) if (is.list(x)) unlist(x) else rep.int(x, lengths(Company)))
]
#>    ID       Date Company Value2      Date2 Value1  Info1  Info2
#> 1:  1 2021-12-31       1      1 2021-12-31      A Info x Info 1
#> 2:  1 2021-12-31       2      2 2021-12-31      A Info x Info 1
#> 3:  1 2021-12-31       3      3 2021-12-31      A Info x Info 1
#> 4:  2 2022-12-31       1      7 2023-03-31      B Info y Info 2
#> 5:  2 2022-12-31       2      8 2023-03-31      B Info y Info 2
#> 6:  2 2022-12-31       3      9 2023-03-31      B Info y Info 2
#> 7:  2 2022-12-31       4     10 2023-03-31      B Info y Info 2
```

Data

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(ID = 1:2,
                  Date = c(dmy("31122021"), dmy("31122022")),
                  Value1 = c("A", "B"),
                  Info1  = c("Info x", "Info y"),
                  Info2  = c("Info 1", "Info 2"))

dt2 <- data.table(ID = c(rep(1, times=6), rep(2, 8)),
                  Company = c(1:3, 1:3, 1:4, 1:4),
                  Date = c(rep(dmy("31122021"), times=3),
                           rep(dmy("31032022"), times=3),
                           rep(dmy("31032023"), times=4),
                           rep(dmy("30062023"), times=4)),
                  Value2 = 1:14)
```

---

### Benchmarking

I should point out that a double join is more performant, if that is a concern.

Solutions as functions:

```
fCollapse <- function(dt1, dt2) {
  setkey(
    setcolorder(
      dt2[
        # "collapse" Company and Value2
        ,.(Company = .(Company), Value2 = .(Value2), Date2 = Date), .(ID, Date)
      ][
        dt1, on = .(ID, Date), roll = "nearest" # perform the rolling join
      ][
        # "expand" the collapsed columns back out
        ,lapply(.SD, \(x) if (is.list(x)) unlist(x) else rep.int(x, lengths(Company)))
      ], c(names(dt1), "Company", "Date2", "Value2")
    ), ID, Date2, Date
  )
}
```

The double join (modified from @r2Evans' answer):

```
fDouble <- function(dt1, dt2) {
  setkey(dt1, ID, Date)
  setkey(dt2, ID, Date)
  setcolorder(
    setnames(
      dt2[
        unique(
          dt2[, Date1 := Date][dt1, roll = "nearest"][
            , c("Company", "Value2") := NULL
          ]
        ),
        on = .(ID, Date = Date1)
      ][,Date1 := NULL],
      c("i.Date", "Date"), c("Date", "Date2")
    ), c(names(dt1), "Company", "Date2", "Value2")
  )
}
```

Create a larger benchmarking dataset.

```
dt1 <- unique(
  data.table(
    ID = sample(100, 1e4, 1),
    Date = as.Date(sample(18000:19000, 1e4, 1))
  )
)[, `:=`(
  Value1 = sample(LETTERS, .N, 1),
  Info1 = paste("Info", sample(letters, .N, 1)),
  Info2 = paste("Info", sample(100, .N, 1))
)]

dt2 <- data.table(
  ID = sample(100, 1e4, 1),
  Company = sample(100, 1e4, 1),
  Date = as.Date(sample(18000:19000, 1e4, 1)),
  Value2 = 1:1e4
)
```

Check that the answers are the same.

```
identical(
  setorder(fDouble(copy(dt1), copy(dt2))),
  setorder(fCollapse(copy(dt1), copy(dt2)))
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fCollapse = fCollapse(DT1, DT2),
  fDouble = fDouble(DT1, DT2),
  setup = {DT1 <- copy(dt1); DT2 <- copy(dt2)}
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  fCollapse 34.1741 37.45145 40.526797 39.28565 41.27445 94.1319   100
#>    fDouble  7.3764  7.67590  8.094951  7.85010  8.10155 12.4141   100
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution! FYI: for me, the backslash syntax in `\(x)` didn't work, but I could simply replace it with `function (x)`.

Comment: You may be interested in the benchmark in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, the  benchmark is quite helpful. In this particular case I'm not much concerned about performance, but good to know that in case performance is important, @r2Evans solution is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Not much better than your hack, but a different approach:

```r
dt2[
  unique(dt2[, Date1 := Date][dt1, .(ID, Date=Date1, Value1), roll = -Inf]),
  on=.(ID, Date)]
#       ID Company       Date Value2      Date1 Value1
#    <int>   <int>     <Date>  <int>     <Date> <char>
# 1:     1       1 2021-12-31      1 2021-12-31      A
# 2:     1       2 2021-12-31      2 2021-12-31      A
# 3:     1       3 2021-12-31      3 2021-12-31      A
# 4:     2       1 2023-03-31      7 2023-03-31      B
# 5:     2       2 2023-03-31      8 2023-03-31      B
# 6:     2       3 2023-03-31      9 2023-03-31      B
# 7:     2       4 2023-03-31     10 2023-03-31      B
```

It still has the (slightly-)unenviable need for `Date1`, necessary because without it, our intermediate step produces

```r
dt2[dt1, .(ID, Date, Value1), roll=-Inf]
#       ID       Date Value1
#    <int>     <Date> <char>
# 1:     1 2021-12-31      A
# 2:     1 2021-12-31      A
# 3:     1 2021-12-31      A
# 4:     2 2022-12-31      B
```

which does not let us join back on `dt2` with its original `Date`. Instead, we do this:

```r
dt2[, Date1:=Date][dt1, .(ID, Date=Date1, Value1), roll=-Inf]
#       ID       Date Value1
#    <int>     <Date> <char>
# 1:     1 2021-12-31      A
# 2:     1 2021-12-31      A
# 3:     1 2021-12-31      A
# 4:     2 2023-03-31      B
```

in order to preserve the original `Date` so that we can join it back (after `unique(.)`) back onto `dt2` to bring all associated rows back in.

Comment: Thanks, this looks much cleaner; however, I struggle a bit with implementing this solution to my real data set, which has many more columns in dt1 that I all want to keep as well. I adjust my question to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of getting the correct answer with `dplyr`:

```
left_join(dt1, dt2, by = "ID") %>%
 group_by(ID, Company) %>%
 mutate(diffdate = abs(Date.x - Date.y)) %>%
 filter(diffdate == min(diffdate)) %>%
 ungroup()

# Output:
     ID Date.x     Value1 Company Date.y     Value2 diffdate
  <dbl> <date>     <chr>    <int> <date>      <int> <drtn>  
1     1 2021-12-31 A            1 2021-12-31      1  0 days 
2     1 2021-12-31 A            2 2021-12-31      2  0 days 
3     1 2021-12-31 A            3 2021-12-31      3  0 days 
4     2 2022-12-31 B            1 2023-03-31      7 90 days 
5     2 2022-12-31 B            2 2023-03-31      8 90 days 
6     2 2022-12-31 B            3 2023-03-31      9 90 days 
7     2 2022-12-31 B            4 2023-03-31     10 90 days
```

Comment: can do a data.table version if you want! :-)